# windows server task scheduler works manual but not auto

Tags: php, windows, scheduled-tasks

i'm having problem with task scheduler for php script, when i click run manual in task scheduler works, also the timer runs perfect, but not the auto

I try several ways but cant make it work

First shoot

```
path:C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
program script:/c C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.exe -f C:\wamp64\www\SportAccess\conciliar_eventos.php
```

Second shoot:

```
path:C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.exe
program script:-f C:\wamp64\www\SportAccess\conciliar_evento.php
```

Comment: And what do the error logs say when it doesn't work?

Comment: No error with the trigger, and apparently "runs" but in status from the last run said "The task is currently running". But also, if i go to the task scheduler, select the task and click on run manual, works perfectly. That is weird